# Identify A, B and C and write the chemical equation

Tags: coordination-compounds

[image]

Please solve this question. I really want to know what is the answer of this question. Please help.

Comment: "Nickle", eh? :D

Comment: @paracetamol Looks like **Nickie** to me, must be some girl in the lab...

Comment: We are not here to do your homework.

Comment: I wonder what they mean with $\ce{C{0}_2}$ and $\ce{H2{0}}$

Answer (score 1):

Second sentence just says us that 1 mole of C contains 2 moles of carbon atoms and 6 moles of H atoms, and we don't really know whether O is present. Thus the formula of C is C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>6</sub>O<sub>x</sub>.
Though reaction of B with hydrogen in presence of Ni forming C gives a clue that B was an alkene or alkyne, and C is an alkane, and C has no oxygens.
Moreover, alcohols are known to give up water in presence of sulfuric acid to form alkenes. 
In this case, C is ethane C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>6</sub>, B is ethene C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>4</sub> and A is ethyl alcohol C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>5</sub>OH.

Comment: Avoid answering homework type question.